# RocksDB: static library size that's built from source is really large

Tags: c++, makefile, rocksdb

When I build [RocksDB](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) using `make static_lib` that produces a 200MB+ `librocksdb.a` file, but when I install the same version through a package manager (compared to both [Brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/rocksdb.rb) and [apt](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rocksdb/4.1-1)), the `.a` file is only about 11MB. What am I missing?

Size of the library when building from source using `make static_lib`:

```
ubuntu@local:~/rocksdb-4.1$ du -sh librocksdb.a
238M    librocksdb.a
```

Size of the library installed using `sudo apt-get install librocksdb-dev` on Xenial:

```
ubuntu@local:~/rocksdb-4.1$ du -sh /usr/lib/librocksdb.a
11M /usr/lib/librocksdb.a
```

Why is there such a big difference?

Comment: Probably the smaller achive is stripped of debug information.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Indeed. I was not aware of strip. Just confirmed it, thanks - can you please add that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the smaller achive is stripped of debug information.

You can use the [`strip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) command to remove symbols.